# Find symbol dependencies in source code

Tags: version-control

I had a bug today that made me wonder about tools to check for the consistency of source code. First, the bug:

My jQuery selector was expecting `.attached_reports`, but the HTML template was creating a div with class `attached-reports`. What happened is that our zealous themer decided to standardize all class names to use hyphens instead of underscores, and our code broke as a result.

The question:
Is there a tool or methodology that would parse the source code, and associate each occurrence of `attached-reports` together. Then, if one of the symbols is changed (e.g. upon version control commit), it can alert the team of the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is cross-language consistency checker, that can statically check for errors that might occur at runtime.

To do this, you need a tool that can process all the languages in question (you have two: Javascript? [for Jquery] with special references to HTML templates,  and the HTML template langauges (which is not exactly HTML).   The tool has to know the JavaScript code will reference templates using a name (presumably this is just a string; how do you know the template name isn't computed by some arcane process?), and that HTML template entries will be referenced (if there is a template slot that isn't referenced, is that OK?)

The world is full of funny little languages and funnier constraints in and between them (and its getting worse as people invent ever-more DSLs and integration rules).  Your're unlikely to find an off-the-shelf tool for every combination.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is designed to accept new language descriptions or dialect variations easily (so you can define the HTML template variant) and custom analyzers (so that you might detection violations).  [DMS already has a stable of conventional and unconventional [Language Front Ends](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds) including one for [JavaScript](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/ECMAScriptFrontEnd.html). DMS is scalable in several dimensions; one is the number of languages it can process at the same time... such as "two" as in your case.

DMS enables one to code custom analyzers or transformers.  Of course whatever analysis is implemented is subject to computability constraints; it is unlikely that if your template name is computed by arcane JavaScript code that the tool would be able to determine if that computed name matched something in the templates.

Comment: Thanks for the reinforcement - what you describe is indeed what I'm looking for. Now to find an open source toolchain that can implement it!

Comment: Well, you can always try to build such a tool with just a (OSS) parser like ANTLR.  In my experience, you always need more than parsers can provide; in your case, you need essentially at least symbol tables for each language.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Comment: The only OSS toolchains comparable to DMS in their conceptual flexibility are Stratego/XT and TXL.  Stratego/XT follows the "LifeAfterParsing" idea to provide *rewrite* rules but nothing else; TXL provides symbol tables in an unusual way as well as rewrite rules but nothing else.  And I don't know how good their JavaScript parsers are, if indeed such exist; you may have fix such and create from scratch.  DMS has full JavaScript and HTML parsers, and support for building dialects (as you need for HTML templates) of those.

Comment: Thanks for the OSS pointers - great starting point. Marking this as the right answer.