# generate diagram of "include" relationships between source code files

Tags: include, code-analysis, tex

I want to do some refactoring of code, especially the "include"-like relationships between files. There are quite a few of them, and to get started, it would be helpful to have a list, diagram, or even a columnar graph, so that I can see at a glance what is included from where.

(In many cases, a given file is included by multiple other files, so the graph would be a DAG, not a tree. There are no cycles.)

I'm working with TeX (actually ConTeXt), but the question would seem to apply to any programming languages that has a facility like that of `#include` in C.

The obvious, easy answer is to do a `grep` or "Find in Files" on all the .tex files for the relevant keywords (`\usemodule`, `\input`, and a couple of other macros we've defined). This is better than nothing, but the output is long, and it's still difficult to see patterns in what includes what. For example, is file A usually included before file B? Is file C ever included multiple times by the same file?

I guess that brings out an additional, but optional feature: that such a tool would be able to show the *sequence* of includes from a particular file. So in that case the DAG could be a multigraph, i.e. there could be multiple arcs from one file to another.

Ideally, it would be nice to be able to annotate each file, giving a very brief summary of what's in it. This would form part of the text on the graph node for that file.

Probably this sort of thing could be done with a script that generates graphviz dot language. But I wanted to know if it has already been done, rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Whoever voted to close as "off topic", care to comment? This is a question about programming / software development, as is expected on SO (TeX is a full programming language, BTW). Suggestions for improvement to fit SO, or for a more appropriate venue, are welcome. I considered the TeX SE site, but the question is more general than that, and I think it's more likely that I'll find a ready-made general solution than a TeX-specific one.

Comment: I think this is a good question. It's also a hard problem because you don't know if there are spurious #include statements.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for chiming in. Spurious, meaning that they refer to nonexistent files? I wouldn't think that would be too hard to deal with ... you could just show the nonexistent file as another node, perhaps with a different shape or background color to show that it doesn't exist. Or maybe I'm missing the point? Alternately, the diagramming tool could emit an error for spurious #include statements. Or ignore them.

Comment: Meaning #include statements that have no effect because the code doesn't actually use anything that was included. (usually, ones that are outright missing would be an error)

Comment: @Mike, I wouldn't expect the tool to do anything special with #include statements that have "no effect" (a criterion that would require much more language-specific analysis, and in some cases would be equivalent to the halting problem... as you say, a hard problem). That kind of analysis is beyond the scope of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Here is [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954879/find-symbol-dependencies-in-source-code) with an answer referencing a commerical tool. Is this an option to you?

Comment: @Stan: thanks for the helpful link. I would +1 if it were an answer. DMS SRT looks useful, and the prices are reasonable. However I think it's overkill for what I need; it's so ambitious, and I was not able to find out quickly whether the feature I'm looking for (tracing includes) is part of their design. TeX is not supported yet, tho that may not be a big hurdle since DMS is designed to be extensible. It's probably simpler to roll my own than to learn their tool... tho the latter would doubtless pay far-reaching dividends.

Comment: I think you'll not find anything ready-made for TeX, because the task is very specific in the context of TeX. So, only extendable tools should be considered. But extendable means massive, and consequently - "overkill" ;-).

Comment: @Stan, I agree except for the last sentence. A tool whose *purpose* is narrowly focused, but that is extensible to different languages, needn't be massive (e.g. yacc). But sure there is a tendency for a focused tool to undergo scope creep.

Comment: Sounds like a job for graphviz to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is friday in my country right now, and I'm waiting for my colleagues to go to have a beer, I thought I'd do a little programming.

Here http://www.luki.webzdarma.cz/up/IncludeGraph.zip you can download source of a really simple utility that looks for all files in one folder, parses #includes and generates a .dot file for that.

It supports and correctly handles relative paths, and works on windows and should work on linux as well. It is written in very spartan way. My version of dot is not parsing the generated files, there is some bug, but I really need to go drinking now, see if you can fix it. I'm not a regular dot user and I dont see it, though I'm sure it is pretty obvious.

Enjoy ...

PS - If you run into trouble compiling and/or running, please let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Ok, my bad, there was a few glitches on linux. The dot problem was it was using "graph" instead of "digraph". But it is working like charm now. Here is the [link](http://www.luki.webzdarma.cz/up/igraph.tgz). Just type make, and if that goes, make test should generate the following diagram of the program itself:

[image: An inclusion graph]

It ignores preprocessor directives in the C++ files so it is not very useful for that directly (could be fixed by simply calling g++ with preprocessor output flag and processing that instead of the actual files). I didn't get to regexp today, but if you have any programming experience, you will find that modifying DotGraph.cpp shouldn't be very hard to hard-code your inclusion token, and to change list of file extensions. Might get to regexp tomorrow or something.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Na zdraví! Unfortunately I don't have Visual Studio though, so it may take me a while. I'd like to go ahead and award the bounty before it expires though... Anybody else want to compile, run it and post sample output?

Comment: I went ahead and accepted this answer, to be sure the bounty was awarded. You wrote a program to do this, so you deserve it. :-) I would like to see your program fixed and published. Bonus points to be awarded for: a) porting the code to where it can be compiled with free tools; b) allowing the user to specify at run time (e.g. in a config file) the set of regexps for "include" statements. The latter is important to my case because we use some custom macros for including certain files.

Comment: The first should be fairly simple, I'll write a makefile or CMakeFile to do that. The code is portable already. The latter should also be fairly easy. I'll let you know once it is done.

Comment: Very nice! (filler text)

Comment: The links provided no longer works, what is the current way of doing this exact thing?

Comment: The link appears to have been from a student's reserved webspace.  Quite possibly lost for good now.  Downvoting this answer, as it is clearly no longer a good answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks for the heads up. Let me fix the links.

Comment: @MertSaner Should work now.

Comment: Can you give some information about how does it work? I also wonder does it create everything automatically or do you define everything manually inside of dot file and then it creates graph diagram in png file?

Comment: @twe swine How does this thing work?

Comment: @MertSaner Lol have you even looked at the source? It parses through the files and generates a dot, which you can use to generate a png. This can be completely scripted with shell, path to source in, png out.

Comment: @the swine Do you manually define these relationships or does it make them automatically? Yes, I did download and spent time on it.

Comment: There is nothing manual.

Comment: @theswine I mean, do you create inclusion.dot file yourself manually? If not how do you create it automatically?

Comment: @theswine Where should I place my own folders? How does this program work?

Comment: In my case it does not create inclusion.dot and inclusion.png, they are already in the folder and if I delete them, it does not create new ones with $make , I did not understand how this will work with some other C++ program, considering it does not creates inclusion.dot itself

Comment: What is the regexp to feed structure? How to use that?

Comment: @Developer `use DotGraph <folder-with-files>`. It adds common c++ file extensions to the search patterns. You can see them added at the beginning of `main()`. If it does not work, you may need to debug the code. You're asking for support on 10 years old code. As far as I know, it works. I still use the same framework on occasion and have not had issues listing out files. Maybe make sure the binary has permissions to access file system.

Comment: @Developer Just tested it now, `make` and `make test` generates the `.dot` and `.png` files just fine.

Comment: @theswine Yes, `make test`, make it work, now I need to create that png file for my own project. How can I do that? So far I have added my files to that folder with files and added header files to DotGraph.Cpp and also added them to the makefile by changing their extention from .h to .o

Comment: @asdf You know that `make test` just calls `dgraph .` where `.` is the current directory, right? Just change `.` to whatever directory your source is in and it will create a graph of that.

Comment: How to do that? It is too complicated men. I have spent some time on it, but it did not work, but I think step by step procedure will both be good for me and for the newcomers to the topic. It will be good if you describe everything and every command we need to execute to run this thing in our machines in our program. When you say . do you mean inclusion. dot file? Is other .h/.cpp files also important?    Some explanation is needed for everything. I think you can also update your answer afterwards as well.

Comment: It's the same as using any other command. E.g. `ls .` will list the current folder contents (or `dir` on Windows). `ls abc` will list folder `abc`. I suggest you learn more about common command-line tools first. There is nothing uncommon or complicated here.

Answer (score 2):

A clever and general solution would be to trace the build system (using something like strace, LD_PRELOAD, patching the binaries, or some other debugging facility).

Once you'd collected the sequence of file open/close operations, you'd just have to filter out the uninteresting stuff, it should be easy to build the dependency tree for any language as long as the following assumptions are true:

1. The build system will open each file when it is included.
2. The build system will close each file when it reaches its end.

Unfortunately, a well-written or poorly-written compiler might violate these assumptions by for instance only opening a file the first time it is included, or never closing any files.

Perhaps because of these limitations, I'm not aware of any implementation of this idea.

On the other hand, clever build systems may include functionality to compute or extract dependencies themselves.  gcc has the `-M` option to output dependencies, and javac figures out dependencies on its own (although I don't know how to get it to output them).

As far as TeX goes, I don't know enough TeX to actually implement this, but conceptually it seems like it should be possible to redefine the low-level include to command to:

1. write a log of what is about to be included
2. call the original include command to include it
3. write a log of what was included

You could then build your tree from the log output.

Comment: Those are some interesting ideas. Regarding the first, yes I can see how those assumptions might often be broken, especially for *conditional* (e.g. mode-based) includes. Regarding the second, redefining the `\input` command (or defining a wrapper function and using it) does sound like a handy way to track includes (except for conditional ones). I'm not sure if the log output you suggest would give us an advantage over the source code itself tho, for creating a diagram... maybe if you crafted it right.